# Is there a definition for the "same" sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am reading a book (Real Analysis 1 by Terence Tao), where the author presents a proof that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^{n} = 0$ for $0 < x < 1$. In the middle of the proof, he says following:

> ...... But the sequence $(x^{n+1})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is just the sequence $(x^{n})_{n=2}^{\infty}$ shifted by one, and so they must have the same limits ......

If one writes down the first elements of both sequences, it becomes obvious that these two sequences are indeed "the same":

$$(x^{2},x^{3},x^{4},\cdots)$$

However, these two sequences are not equal (unless I am misunderstanding the definition of the sequences). By definition (the one presented in the book), a sequence $(a_{i})_{i=m}^{\infty}$ is defined as a function $f: \{n \mid n ≥ m\} \rightarrow \mathbb R$, where $f(i) = a_i$. Using this definition, one can see that the sequences $(x^{n+1})_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $(x^{n})_{n=2}^{\infty}$ cannot be equal, since the function corresponding to the sequence $(x^{n+1})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ has $1$ in its domain, but the function corresponding to $(x^{n})_{n=2}^{\infty}$ does not (i.e., the underlying functions have different domains, hence they are not equal, which means the sequences are not equal).

In fact, even if one takes a simple sequence $(1,2,3,\cdots)$, one can find infinitely many ways to denote such sequence (e.g. $(n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $(n-1)_{n=2}^{\infty}$, $(n-2)_{n=3}^{\infty}$ etc.), and according to our definition, all of those denotations refer to the different sequences (i.e., $(n)_{n=1}^{\infty} ≠ (n-1)_{n=2}^{\infty}$, $(n)_{n=1}^{\infty} ≠ (n-2)_{n=3}^{\infty}$ etc.)

**Question**.

Is there an alternative definition that would allow us to equalize sequences like $(n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, $(n-1)_{n=2}^{\infty}$, $(n-2)_{n=3}^{\infty}$ or sequences like $(x^{n+1})_{i=1}^{\infty}$, $(x^{n})_{i=2}^{\infty}$?

---

There is one particular reason why I think this alternative definition could be useful. Let's consider an example:

Let $0 < x < 1$. Also let's assume that we've already shown that the sequence $(x^{n})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent to $L$. It is clear that sequences $(x^{n-1})_{i=2}^{\infty}$,$(x^{n-2})_{i=3}^{\infty}$, $(x^{n-3})_{i=4}^{\infty}$ $\cdots$ are the "same" as $(x^{n})_{i=1}^{\infty}$, in a sense that they all correspond to the sequence

$$(x^{2},x^{3},x^{4},\cdots)$$

And hence is it quite reasonable to conclude that those sequences must also converge to $L$. However, since all those sequences are not equal to each other, without rigorous definition of "sameness", the claim should be justified for each sequence separately. For example, if we want to show that $(x^{n-1})_{i=2}^{\infty}$ also converges to $L$, we need to take $\epsilon > 0$ and find an $N$ such that for all $n ≥ N$, $|a^{n-1} - L| ≤ \epsilon$ (it is easy to do so, of course, but is rather cumbersome; what's worse, we still need to show the convergence for the sequences $(x^{n-2})_{i=3}^{\infty}$, $(x^{n-3})_{i=4}^{\infty}$). But if one can come with a rigorous definition of "sameness", the notion of convergence of the "same" sequences can be generalized.

Comment: You can define a sequence as the ordered image of an application $f: \{n \mid n ≥ m\} \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, you could define $(a_i)_{i=m}^\infty$ as the function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$, $f(i)=a_{m-1+i}$.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvoted. The OP is asking how to make sequences with the exact same elements be set-theoretically equal - not anything about tail equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is the *tail* of a sequence. This is another sequence that starts at the $n$th element of the first one, where $n$ is some unspecified positive integer. You could then say that the sequences $(x^n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(x^{n-1})_{n=2}^\infty$ have the same tail, which would mean that there must exist integers $m$ and $k$ such that $(x^n)_{n=m}^\infty$ and $(x^{n-1})_{n=k}^\infty$ are the same sequence.

Because we leave the starting point of the tail unspecified, we can choose $m$ and $k$ freely and independently. A more rigorous way of saying this is that a sequence does not have one tail, but instead a set of tails: one for each starting point.
One would then speak of "a tail" instead of "the tail", and "There exist tails of these two sequences that are equal". This rigor does clog up the language though, hence the use of "the tail" in my example above.

This term is also useful for making concise statements about sequences whose first elements behave rather erratically. For example: let $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ be the sequence specified by $x_0 = 5$, $x_1 = 123456789$, and $x_n = 0$ for all integers $n>1$, then the tail of this sequence consists of only zeros.

Note that only the behaviour of the tail of a sequence matters for determining its limit. This is the reason this term is so useful.

Comment: Downvoter, care to leave a reply indicating what you didn't like/what I could improve about my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your response (sorry for the late reply). I didn't downote, but your answer is not exactly what I want. "Tail" of a sequence is an informal term (or at least I didn't see rigorous definition of "tail" in the nextbook), but if I am not mistaken, when people are saying that tails of sequences $(a_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$,$(b_{i})_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are equal, they mean that there exists some $N ≥ 1$ such that for all $n ≥ N$, $a_n = b_n$  .....

Comment: .....  Under this definition of "equal tails" and standard definition of a sequence (I've mentioned it in the original post),  sequences $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} = (x^{n+1})_{n=1}$ and $(a_{n})_{n=2}^{\infty}=(x^{n})_{n=2}^{\infty}$ do not have any equal tails, since $b_i = x^{i+1}$ but $a_i = x^{i}$ for all $i ≥ 2$.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, this is an informal term, and I guess not many textbooks will define it, but it has a lot  of relevant google results. I don't think there exists a better term that describes what you need it to. Where did you hear about tails of sequences being equal only if they start at the same $N$? If it is something you inferred from my post, that is not how I'd use it, but I guess it's also valid. If you want to be clear with your language, you can always use "some tails of these sequences are equal". Can we agree on that? If you do, I'll edit. If not, we can work it out.

Comment: I just thought of another way: I'm fairly certain the relation you're describing is an equivalence relation. You could explicitly define it and say sequences are equivalent. I could add that in too.